# How can I request to camel-context endpoints from postman?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, postman

I have a spring project using apache camel.
I want to try the services provided in camel-context.xml using a postman request.
How can I infer the path variables and endpoint?

The method I want to use is specified like below on camel-context.xml and I have parameters providing the contains conditions.

```
            <route>
        <from uri="netty:udp://{{camel.netty.server}}:{{camel.netty.udp.port}}?sync=false&amp;allowDefaultCodec=true;" />           
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" charset="ISO-8859-9" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple trim="true">${bodyAs(String)} contains '"ISN":"90"'</simple>                    
                <bean ref="Feaser" method="run" cache="false"></bean>
                <to uri="mock:result" />
            </when>
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman doesn't support sending on UDP.

Comment: Thanks, I am new with netty, can you share the right approach to send a request to netty services? I need to trigger that service somehow.

Comment: I don't do much UDP, so would have to search for it. I recommend that.